# Esclipse for both PHP and Client-side Scripts?

Tags: eclipse

How can i setup my Eclipse to develop `php` and client side scripts like `javascripts` `html` `css` all in one?

Comment: how about reading the manual of Eclipse? install PHP Development Tool (PDT) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ZendStudio (which actually is Eclipse):
http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads

Here is comparison with eclipse PDT:

http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/comparison